# Unable to execute the query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to execute the SQL query, but getting 'Missing right parenthesis' error:

```
((SELECT CUST_ACCT 
  FROM CUSTMASTER 
  WHERE SITE_ID IN (SELECT SITE_ID FROM HOUSEMASTER WHERE FTAX=1)) 
  AND
 (SELECT CUST_ACCT 
  FROM CUSTMASTER 
  WHERE SITE_ID IN (SELECT SITE_ID FROM  HOUSEMASTER WHERE MGT=1)))
```

I feel like the parenthesis are properly checked. Please let me know what is missing?

Comment: You might want to edit your question with a description of the tables and the output you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the results from two different queries as one by adding a `and` operator between them. This won't work. You could use a `union` query, but it looks like it can be reduced to the query below.

Maybe this is what you really wanted?

```
SELECT CUST_ACCT 
FROM CUSTMASTER 
WHERE SITE_ID IN (
    SELECT SITE_ID 
    FROM HOUSEMASTER 
    WHERE FTAX=1 OR MGT=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there have to be UNION:

```
((SELECT CUST_ACCT 
  FROM CUSTMASTER 
  WHERE SITE_ID IN (SELECT SITE_ID 
                    FROM HOUSEMASTER 
                    WHERE FTAX = 1)) 
  UNION
  (SELECT CUST_ACCT 
   FROM CUSTMASTER 
   WHERE SITE_ID IN (SELECT SITE_ID FROM HOUSEMASTER WHERE MGT=1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM CUSTMASTER WHERE SITE_ID
 IN (SELECT SITE_ID FROM HOUSEMASTER WHERE FTAX=1 or MGT=1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly cause your description is not detail.

try this if you try to compare just like `select (true and false)`:

**SELECT** ((SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM CUSTMASTER WHERE SITE_ID IN (SELECT SITE_ID FROM HOUSEMASTER WHERE FTAX=1)) AND (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM CUSTMASTER WHERE SITE_ID IN (SELECT SITE_ID FROM HOUSEMASTER WHERE MGT=1)))